# Analysing data in pandas where some values are lists of dicts

Tags: python, list, pandas, dictionary, nested

I was given a stupid csv with like 20,000 rows of data pertaining to only ~300 cases, so I wanted to try and group things in a way that made more sense, so I now have a text file with 300 cases, a sample of two of them are below:

[{"Treatment": [""], "Year": "2004", "Reason": "Intentional/Suspected Suicide", "CaseNumber": "9999", "OutCome": "Minor effect", "Symptoms": ["Drowsy/lethargy / Related"], "case_drugs": [{"Substance": "RIVOTRIL", "Poisindex_Desc": "BENZODIAZEPINE", "SubstanceFormula_20c": "LIQUID", "SubstanceProductCode": "999", "RouteExp": "INGEST", "SubstanceGeneric_AAPCC_Code": "999"}, {"Substance": "HYDROMORPHONE X 15 SYRINGES 6 MG EA", "Poisindex_Desc": "HYDROMORPHONE", "SubstanceFormula_20c": "LIQUID", "SubstanceProductCode": "9999", "RouteExp": "INGEST", "SubstanceGeneric_AAPCC_Code": "9999"}], "Acuity": "Acute", "AgeGroup": "90-99 yrs", "SEX": "zoidberg"},
{"Treatment": ["Single Dose Activated Charcoal", "IV Fluids"], "Year": "2006", "Reason": "Unintentional/General", "CaseNumber": "8888", "OutCome": "Minimal clinical effects possible", "Symptoms": [""], "case_drugs": [{"Substance": "LOPERAMIDE 2MG X 1/2", "Poisindex_Desc": "LOPERAMIDE", "SubstanceFormula_20c": "SOLID (TABLETS/CAPSULES/CAPLETS)", "SubstanceProductCode": "88", "RouteExp": "INGEST", "SubstanceGeneric_AAPCC_Code": "88"}], "Acuity": "Acute", "AgeGroup": "L5 yrs", "SEX": "F"}]

Something like "Year" only has 1 value for each case. "Symptoms" has a list of values, and "case_drugs" has a list of dicts. This format makes a lot of sense to me since 1 person can have multiple drugs, and each drug has multiple attributes associated with it. I don't really want to flatten the data because something like the drug variable doesn't really have a maximum number of entries, so it's possible that if I have like "drug1, drug2, drug3" then next time I get data I'll have to add a "drug4".

Currently, I can load the file in pandas and analyze most of it. For the list values, I've come across another stack exchange post that suggested I could use this:

> `df['Symptoms'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).value_counts()).sum()`

That works perfectly. I'm sure I can figure out how to do other analysis with a similar method. I still am unsure how I will go about analyzing the case_drugs variable. I can make my own functions to loop through and read the data, but I was wondering if there is existing functionality in pandas that will be able to do this. For example, what if I wanted to count the number of times 'RIVOTRIL' showed up in the "substance" value of "case_drugs" variable?

Or if you think I'd be better off storing the data in a different way, that would be an acceptable answer too!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the `case_drugs` variable, one way to do it is to create another dataframe for it.

```
df_case_drugs = pd.DataFrame(df['case_drugs'].values[0])
df_case_drugs['Substance'].value_counts()
>>>
RIVOTRIL                               1
HYDROMORPHONE X 15 SYRINGES 6 MG EA    1
```

**Update**:
Creating a dataframe that includes all the entries in `case_drugs`.

I would first split (explode) the list of dicts in `case_drugs` to its own row and use `CaseNumber` as the index.

```
df_case_drugs = pd.DataFrame(df['case_drugs'].tolist(), index=df['CaseNumber']).stack()
df_case_drugs = df_case_drugs.reset_index()
```

This gives you a dataframe with one dict per row in the column named 0. (You can rename the column, but we are not keeping this column anyway so it doesn't really matter.)

Then convert the dicts into a dataframe.

```
df_case_drugs = pd.concat([df_case_drugs['CaseNumber'], 
    pd.DataFrame(df_case_drugs[0].tolist())], axis=1)
```

Count values:

```
df_case_drugs['Substance'].value_counts()
>>>
RIVOTRIL                               1
LOPERAMIDE 2MG X 1/2                   1
HYDROMORPHONE X 15 SYRINGES 6 MG EA    1
```

Comment: Thanks! I like this solution. To do this for all of the values in case_drugs, I did the following:


`df_case_drugs = pd.DataFrame(pcc['case_drugs'].values[0])
for x in pcc['case_drugs'].values[1:]:df_case_drugs = 
    df_case_drugs.append(pd.DataFrame(x))
df_case_drugs['Substance'].value_counts()`

Do you think there's a simpler way? Also, how would I go about adding in a column to this new DF to include the 'CaseNumber' variable?

Comment: @melonfacedoom I edited my answer to expand the solution. Hope this is what you are looking for.